# False information about disk usage using Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've probably read 2 dozen articles about Docker and disk space. But I can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

I have a 75GB drive that gets 100% used after a few days. Then I reboot the server and it has all its space back again...

[image]

I have ran

```
sudo docker system prune --all --force
```

It reclaimed a bit, but not much.

I have 5 containers running

[image]

Any ideas on how I can tell where this disk space is going?

Comment: Assuming that we don't know what processes you run inside your container, if there are any logs, databases or any other generated data, do they update themselves automatically, etc. I'm sure you will find this one helpfull: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/sorting-files-according-to-size-recursively

Comment: If reboot is solving your problem, it's most likely cause is open files which were deleted. check if this command gives any output, if so pls share`lsof |grep -i "deleted"`

Comment: What does `docker info --format '{{.Driver}}'` show?

Comment: Possibility of some malware?

Answer (score 0):

`docker system df` will tell you where Docker thinks the data being used

`du -sm /var/lib/docker/*` will tell you what Docker is using of the physical space on the disk.

`docker system prune` only cleans up unused space.